# GLSL Fragment Shader Bad Values

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

When I try to pass a uniform uint to a fragment shader from a vertex shader, it changes the value. I have confirmed that the value is 1 in the vertex shader by changing the position if the value is not 1. If the value is 1 in the fragment shader, it shows the diffuse texture instead of the diffuse colour. The code is as follows. Also, I have tries passing it as a value within a uniform vec2, but this did not work either.

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 410
// Layouts
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
// Uniforms (matrices)
uniform mat4 model, view, proj;
// Uniforms (texture)
uniform uint useDiffuseTexture;
// Uniforms (shininess)
uniform float shininess;
uniform float shininessStrength;
// Uniforms (colour)
uniform vec3 diffuseColour;
uniform vec3 specularColour;
// Outputs (texture)
out uint UseDiffuseTexture;
out vec2 TexCoord;
// Outputs (colour)
out vec3 DiffuseColour;
out vec3 SpecularColour;
// Outputs (shininess)
out float Shininess;
out float ShininessStrength;
void main() {
    UseDiffuseTexture = useDiffuseTexture;
    TexCoord = texCoord;
    if(useDiffuseTexture == 1)
        gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);
    else
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 410
// Inputs (texture)
in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D diffuseTexture;
// Uniforms (texture)
uniform uint UseDiffuseTexture;
// Uniforms (colour)
uniform vec3 DiffuseColour;
uniform vec3 SpecularColour;
// Uniforms (shininess)
uniform float Shininess;
uniform float ShininessStrength;
// Output
out vec4 fragColour;
void main() {
    vec4 texColour = vec4(DiffuseColour, 1.0);;
    if(UseDiffuseTexture == 1)
        texColour = texture(diffuseTexture, TexCoord);

    if(texColour.a < 0.2)
        discard;

    fragColour = texColour;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fragment shader you declare `uniform uint UseDiffuseTexture`. If you want it to be a value coming from the vertex shader it must be `in uint UseDiffuseTexture`

**Edit**  
Because the input is a unsigned int it must be qualifyied with "flat": `flat in uint UseDiffuseTexture`

Comment: It then says you cant have a uint in as an in in the fragment shader shader. This is the exact message: ERROR: 0:8: unsigned int can't be an in in the fragment shader

Comment: Yes, they can be uint, but then qualify them with `flat`. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dude , wrong definitions :D . Change

```
uniform uint UseDiffuseTexture;
uniform vec3 DiffuseColour;
uniform vec3 SpecularColour;
```

in your fragment shader with

```
in uint UseDiffuseTexture;
in vec3 DiffuseColour;
in vec3 SpecularColour;
```

simply just because you are passing it through the vertex shader and your fragment shader expects 4 INs since your vertex shader has 4 OUTs...

Comment: The original reason I used uniform was whenever I compile it, it says uint can not be an in in a fragment shader.

Comment: did you use glUniform1ui for useDiffuseTexture?

Comment: and btw i would avoid using the same name for variables in GLSL just for safety reasons so you should try to change out uint useDiffuseTexture to : out uint useDiffTex;

Comment: Yes I did, its not passing it to the vertex shader that is the problem. The fragment shader won't even compile if it has a uint or int as a 'in'. This is the exact output:
ERROR: 0:8: unsigned int can't be an in in the fragment shader

Comment: Well this is why : "Fragment shader inputs that are signed or unsigned integers, integer vectors, or any double-precision floating-point type must be qualified with the interpolation qualifier flat." (GL 4.5 specification section 4.3.4 "input variables") , so it will never interpolate uint or int types in GLSL...

Comment: Well , you even made me test it out ... Here is your solution : whenever you have to set something in your fragment shader declare your uniforms there (it worked with float AND bool type pretty nice :) ) . So keep your uniforms in the fragment shader and get rid of them in the vertex shader...

Comment: Ok, thanks, I didn't know you could do that with anything but samplers. That is much more convenient than passing it to the fragment shader!

Comment: anytime , idk why i didn't say that from the beginning... maybe its just because i am tired or so ... :D